# Windows 10 re-installation

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, usb, installation

I've been trying to reinstall Windows 10 x64 on a multimedia computer and have been running into some issues. The reason why I am wanting to reinstall is that I am stuck in a automatic repair boot loop and the easiest solution seemed like just re-formatting and reinstalling windows.

However I've been having issues. I first tried with a USB drive and specifically told it to boot from it. I get to the Windows Icon page and it is stuck for hours. I tried multiple different USB ports thinking one could be bad. Although it recognizes the USB drive in BIOS.

This morning burned a windows 10 iso image on a disc and tried booting directly from the DVD drive. And am getting the same issue with the post stuck on the windows icon page.

I figured this was 100% a windows software issue but am i wrong? What else could i try to do to reinstall windows on this PC?

Any help or insight is much appreciated

Comment: MBR or GPT partitions?

Comment: I'd bet it's failing to install for the same reason it went into the repair boot loop: because something is broken beyond software.  Start troubleshooting for faulty hardware (disks, RAM, etc.).

Comment: @Ramhound I believe MBR but i did not build this one myself. It was done by a coworker

Comment: You need to verify which one.

Comment: As the others before me have said: Start looking at the hardware if it won't boot right.

Just to establish a baseline: You could also try booting a Windows 8.1 or Windows 7 device (USB or DVD).

Remove any unnecessary hardware such as external peripherals (like other USB devices) then move up to secondary hard drives, your CD/DVD ROM, PCIe cards and RAM (try swapping slots, trying 2 at a time - be methodical).

Also, just to confirm: Do you need to backup anything on this machine or are you looking to, as you said, re-format and re-install Windows 10?